# Flutter: Disabling Android System Back Button using WillPopScope NOT WORKING

Tags: android, flutter

I want to disable the android system Back Button but I cannot do it, I used WillPopScope, but I don`t know why is not working, can you help me? I put a part of the code

Thank you

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");
    provider = Provider.of<CentralStoreScreenProvider>(context);
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          return false;
        },
        child:
        Scaffold(
        appBar: searchBar!.build(context),
    drawer: /**/
        body: GoogleMap(
          mapType: MapType.hybrid,
          initialCameraPosition: initialLocation,
          markers: Set.of((marker != null) ? [marker!] : []),
          circles: Set.of((circle != null) ? [circle!] : []),
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
            _controller = controller;
          },
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.location_searching),
            onPressed: () {
              getCurrentLocation();

            }),

      )
    );



  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure you are in statful widget, and check this code for reference.**
*this is my code this works well*

```
   class DashboardScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<DashboardScreen> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          return false;
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.location_searching), onPressed: () {}),
        ));
  }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but I found that with Android 11 the problem is solved but with Android 12 I have the problem, same code, nothing changed, and yes my widget is wrapped in a statful widget.

Comment: Okey. Thanks bro