# The default back button of android not working in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, dart

I used willPopScope but doesn't work. Has anybody any other idea what can I use to overwrite the default back button of Android in Android Studio

The actual result: When I click the back button, it redirects to the login page, not to the page I want.

Does anybody has any other idea about this to function?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using a route system to avoid this behavior as follows: [Navigate with named routes](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/named-routes)
or check out if you're in Stateful widget as this is suggested in this previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71137658/18141665)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It did not work. I have used this method with the route name:

```
void navigateToEventScreen() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    BlocProvider.of<PastHuddleCubit>(context).fetchPastHuddles();
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        navigateToEventScreen();
        return false;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: ProfileAppBar(
          screenTitle: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.huddleScreenTitle,
        ),
```

.....